# mongodb order of array reference when lookup

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have two collection like

```
collA{...}
```

and

```
collB
{
   ...
   data: [{type: ObjectId, ref: 'CollA'}],
}
```

When I using lookup to get reference look like bellow it working perfect but order of array changed

```
{"$lookup": {
    "from": "collA",
    "localField": "data",
    "foreignField": "_id",
    "as": "data"
}},
```

in my example I have

```
collB {
   ...
   data [
      0: collA_0,
      1: collA_1
   ]
 }
```

but when using lookup result like

```
{
   ...
   data [
      0: collA_1,
      1: collA_0
   ]
 }
```

order of that was changed. Is that by default of lookup? how can I sort that again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, When using `$lookup`, the order of the documents returned is not guaranteed. The documents are returned in "natural order" - as they are encountered in the database. The only way to get a guaranteed consistent order is to add a `$sort` stage to the query. If the documents are sorted in the ODM you are using, it's likely inserting a `$sort` or sorting the objects in the ODM itself.

Reference: [MongoDB Jira](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-32947)

You can try out this sample query to sort your output for MongoDB 3.6 and above.

Chekout this documentation for more info [Join Conditions and Subqueries on a Joined Collection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-subqueries-on-a-joined-collection):

```
db.coll1.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      _id: 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "coll2",
      "localField": "data",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      let: {
        "data_id": "$data",
        
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          "$addFields": {
            index: {
              $indexOfArray: [
                "$$data_id",
                "$_id"
              ]
            },
            
          }
        },
        {
          "$sort": {
            index: 1
          }
        },
        {
          "$project": {
            index: 0
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "output"
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the link to playground to test the query [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TsG4GF906Rr)

Comment: Okay... so want to sort them on which key? can you share some sample data and expected output?

Comment: in my question has example. I want it sort by index of array. I think that will correct sort to before lookup

Comment: Okay... can you also mention which version of MongoDB you are using?

Comment: Okay.. you can use the `$lookup` internal `pipeline`... I have updated the answer with the sample query

Answer (score 0):

after $lookup you could $sort result of $lookup

```
[{$unwind: '$data'},
{$sort: {'data._id':-1}},
{$group: {_id: '$_id', 'data': {$push:
'$data._id'}}},
{$project: {'data':
'$data'}}]
```